# How can I add data after the '>' character in my Neoway N58 using qcom tool?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command

I am trying to send data from my Neoway N58 to my phone. The application note mentions that the command to do the same is
`AT+NWBLEPSEND=<srv_id>,<crt_id>,<op>,<mode>, len<CR>`
Input data after the “>” character

here is what the application note illustrates as an example [image: Application note example]

Now i am trying to use the qcom tool to send this AT Command but don't know how to add characters after ">". here is a photo to demonstrate my problem [image: screen grab of my current qcom screen] .since I don't know how to write, lets say "hello" after the ">", the operation expires after 30 seconds. I simply wish to send the hello from here and view it on my BLE Application on my phone.

I am very very new to using AT commands and in general to this IOT type of boards so any help is much appreciated.

When I tried to input data after > as shown here [image: screen grab of my qcom pane] it would simply not let me enter any alphabets or numbers and went straight to operation expire after 30s as i could write any of the data that needed to be sent.

Comment: What happens if you simply send "hello" within the 30 seconds (click the "Send Command" button)? I don't think that you need to post that literally after the prompt character.

Comment: Did you click the "Send Command" button for the "Input string".  Since you are doing this with a tool (QCom) and not with _code_, the question is clearly off-topic.  I suggest you use TeraTerm or PuTTY or similar terminal emulator - QCOM may be just over complicating the issue.

Comment: I did use putty and encountered the same issue.

Comment: My approach at entering the hex string was correct I adjusted the word length from 100 to 5 and it worked just fine. in order to make it transmit hello we would have to hit enter 20 times.

Comment: So this was a simple user error, because you told the device to expect 100 characters, but only gave it 5? Then you might want to delete this question, and because it is not about software development...